# Assistance with elseif

Tags: php

I'm having trouble constructing an **elseif** statement. Within my loop I want to display **one** of the following, in order of preference:

If there's a featured image, echo that. If not echo the custom meta field 'intro-para'. If not echo a limited extract.

So far I have the following, which works fine for the first two conditions:

```
<?php
    if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink()?>"><?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail(get_the_ID(), 'homefeature_thumb'); ?></a>
    <?php }
    else { ?>
    <p><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'intro-para', true); ?></p>
    <?php }
?>
```

I then need to echo the following if neither of the conditions above are met, but am having trouble getting my head around the syntax of the elseif statement with what I have:

```
<?php echo get_limited_excerpt('', '', 230); ?>
```

I'm a bit of a beginner and just feeling my way with PHP at the moment, so any help would be appreciated.

With thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Okay. I figured out how to do this. I assigned a variable to use the value of the custom meta field, which just made things a little easier to visualise (for me):

```
<?php 
    $intro_para_value = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'intro-para', true );
    if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { print get_the_post_thumbnail(get_the_ID(), 'homefeature_thumb'); }
    elseif ( !empty ($intro_para_value)) { echo $intro_para_value; }
    else { echo get_limited_excerpt('', '', 230); }
?>
```

Hope this helps others who might be stuck.